# Migration from Prism 7 to Prism 8

Tags: migration, prism, unity-container

I'm trying to upgrade from Prism 7.1.0.431 to 8.1.97 and I'm having several problems.

I think my biggest problem comes from replacing the "CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.Current" with "Prism.Ioc.ContainerLocator.Container."
(I know this is an anti-pattern,... but that's not the point)

I don't know how to replace : ServiceLocator.Current.**GetAllInstances**<>()

For example in this line of code where I get all the rights available in the application (in modules) that should be assignable to users:

IEnumerable rights = ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<CheckNavigationRights>().SelectMany(c => c.Rights).Distinct();

How can I do the same thing with Prism 8?

I use Unity.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't like Prism's container abstraction, you can use the container-specific static method `GetContainer` to get access to the underlying container:

```
using Prism.Unity;

IEnumerable rights = ContainerLocator.Container.GetContainer().GetAllInstances<CheckNavigationRights>().SelectMany(c => c.Rights).Distinct();
```

BTW: you could inject or resolve an `IEnumerable<CheckNavigationRights>` to get all the named registrations.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear and precise help.